# Application Insights not showing data for Server Response Time, Server Requests or Failed Requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have added Application Insights to my application.

After some time, I am correctly seeing the **Browser Page Load Times**, but none of the other graphs are showing any data at all.

I see this:

[image: Missing Server Data]

When I am expecting something along the lines of this:

[image: What I am expecting]

These are two ASP.NET MVC 5 applications that are in the same solution, and both are deployed to Azure.

In both cases:

1. I have the correct javascript fragment in my razor layout (and have verified via the page source when viewing the website that it is both getting output, and that a request is sent to `dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track`);
2. I have an `ApplicationInsights.config` in the web root;
3. I am setting the correct instrumentation key during application startup, in the `Application_Start()` method of `Global.asax.cs` by way of `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "the_key"`

Please note that I DO NOT have the instrumentation key in the `ApplicationInsights.config` file as I am deploying the website multiple times, and are setting the instrumentation key in accordance with [this advice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions.aspx).

I've reset everything up (following [Add Application Insights SDK to monitor your ASP.NET app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-start-monitoring-app-health-usage/)) but still, after at least 1/2 an hour, I am not seeing anything for Server Response Time, Server Requests or Failed Requests.

How do I fix this?

Comment: To diagnose the issue can you deploy the website to your local IIS and check in Fiddler the requests sent by w3wp process to /track endpoint. Ser if anything is sent and what ikey is used.

Comment: @AlexBulankou thanks.  As mentioned, I viewed the network logs to verify that a request is being sent to the `dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track` endpoint.  In all cases, I see the json payload that includes a timestamp and the `iKey`, which is correct.

Comment: Can you please send me Fiddler payload and ikey to albulank@microsoft.com and I should be able to see whether data sent for this ikey was reaching our data collection servers and when.

Comment: Have you added the [App Insights Site Extension](https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites/) to your app?

Comment: are you seeing the requests to dc from the browser (where the page load time chart is coming from), or from the server?  (does the fiddler trace show pageview/pageperformance events, or is it sending request events)

Comment: @AlexBulankou thanks for the offer.  I've managed to get it sorted out.  I will update the post (or answer my own question) with some details on it shortly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following some offline help from [Alex Bulankou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788382/alex-bulankou), I've resolved the issue.

It was difficult to pinpoint the precise combination that caused the issue, but I suspect it was due to mismatched versions of the Application Insights assemblies, a malformed `ApplicationInsights.config` file and something getting screwed up between adding Application Insights via the Visual Studio command and doing it manually.

The ultimate path to resolution was to:

1. Remove all `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.*` nuget packages from the project;
2. Delete the existing `ApplicationInsights.config` file;
3. Re-add the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web` nuget package **only** - it will install all the required dependencies, including a fresh `ApplicationInsights.config` file (that doesn't have the `iKey`, which is what I wanted - see below)
4. My existing code to set the `InstrumentationKey` via `Global.asax.cs` remained unchanged

End result (I fixed this all at about 7am):

[image: Now tracking Server Requests]

Comment: Thanks for posting this but this seems like a fragile and limiting fix.  What if I need other AppInsights packages later or now for that matter?

Comment: Not at all.  This was probably an issue due to my manual adding of some packages and the fact that App Insights was only in preview at the time.  Moving forward I have experience no issues with App Insights whatsoever.

Comment: for the "manual" part, I'm guessing you mean installing it by hand and not using the nuget from the package manager console? That was probably a huge part of it. Between NuGet, NPM and Bower, I don't see a reason to ever hand install something that's available in one of those feeds/registries.

Comment: I think you're missing the crux of what my issue was, how it got into that state, and what I did you resolve things.  I did note that "manually" referred to using Nuget.

Comment: Thank you for this solution - fixed the same problem I was having!

Comment: Worked for me too. I also deleted AI assembly redirection (in `app.config` and `web.config`), service references, and `ApplicationInsightsResourceId` from the ASP.NET csproj for good measure. I then used Visual Studio's "Add Application Insights Telemetry" (when right-clicking the ASP.NET project). For some reason I had to manually install the `Validation` NuGet before though, or I would get the following error: "Failed to install package: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web with error: Unable to resolve dependency 'Validation'. Source(s) used: 'F:\VS2015\Common7\IDE\Extensions\qdcob2xn.2ox'".

Comment: I had this issue in production - everything worked fine on my dev box, but in production it just did not send any telemetry without any errors or any obvious problems popping up. Based on this post, I decided to clean the whole prod website and copied all binaries & config over again and it started working. Most likely, there were also binaries or configs from some older verison of AppInsights left on the server.